# How to easily construct RDF file from [String] list of concepts in Haskell?

Tags: parsing, haskell, rdf

I'm working on automatic construction of ontologies from program's source code. To make things easier, I'm only interested on functions name and functions calls, in C code source. So my concepts are `functions name` and indeed, relations between those concepts are `function call`.

That means, within a simple Haskell script I can retreive by parsing, all functions name and calls.

Now Here is my question, Is there any **simple**, and **efficient** haskell package for easely transform a simple list of concepts `[String]` in a well designed `RDF` file ?

Thanks for any reply !

Comment: Could you add example input and output?

Answer (score 1):

Out of my depth here, but Graham Klyne and others created a package called [Swish](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/swish) which include RDF output capabilities.

It doesn't include `RDF/XML` output, but does include `N-Triples` and `Turtle` support, which are typically sufficient for interoperability.

(If you care about `RDF/XML` you can always convert using rapper or jena command line tools)